# External access to pythonanywhere MySQL database with pandas and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I want to use `pandas` to read data from my pythonanywhere MySQL database. `pandas` uses `sqlalchemy`.

The following doesn't work:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:pass@user.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/user$db_name')
pd.read_sql('SHOW TABLES from db_name', engine)
```

I'm getting an error: `OperationalError: OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'user.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com' (10060)") None None`

What's wrong? Or is external access not possible with pythonanywhere? (I'm on a free plan)

Comment: Maybe look at https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingSQLAlchemywithMySQL

Comment: @joris Thx, but still doesn't work. If I run the script from within pythonanywhere I get `(OperationalError) (1044, "Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'db_name'") 'SHOW TABLES from db_name' ()`

Comment: @tobip `engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo=False)` This is full detail you need to connect to a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here.  Unfortunately you can't connect to your PythonAnywhere database from outside the service.  If you had a paid plan (which comes with SSH access) then you could do it [by using SSH tunnelling](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SSHTunnelling) but that won't work from a free account.

Comment: Is this the same for Postgres DBs?

Comment: That's right -- all databases are on a private subnet.